# Retrieve index value from with_sequence in ansible

Tags: ansible

how can I retrieve the index "{{ item }}" value that is used in a with_sequence loop in ansible?
I use the following code:

```
- name: Check if Route 53 DNS record exists
  route53:
    state: get
    zone: zone_id
    private_zone: true
    record: testrecord{{ item }}.foo.com
    type: A
  register: dns_record
  when: (dns_record is not defined) or (dns_record.set | length > 0)
  with_sequence: start=0 end=9
```

When this code block exits, I am unable to retrieve the {{ item }} value how can I still use this value later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When this code block exits, I am unable to retrieve the {{ item }} value how can I still use this value later on?

Is not true; if you had examined the variable from your `register:` (with something like `- debug: var=dns_record`) you would have observed there is a `results` list, and it is a `list[dict]` with a top-level key of `item` showing the value of `item` across each iteration

```yaml
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: item is {{ item }}
    with_sequence: start=0 end=5
    register: the_items
  - debug: var=the_items
```

produces

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "the_items": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "item": "0",
                "msg": "item is 0"
            },
```

Comment: Guess I am stupid for not seeing this ... I will have a look at it ... is this the normal way as of how index of loops is returned when using loops?

Comment: You are right, it has all I need, I was not looking at it properly, thank you